# Can I force a complex class to be instantiated when using FromUri attribute in Asp.Net WebApi action without route or query string parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi action defined below.
(I'm using MediatR library which is only slightly relevant to my question)

```
[HttpGet]
[Route]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Search([FromUri] SearchTransactionsRequest request)
{
    var response = await _mediator.Send(request);
    return Ok(response);
}
```

The following URL is routed successfully to my action:

```
/api/v1/transactions
```

However, as I haven't defined any route parameters and I don't always add query string parameters, the class `SearchTransactionRequest` will sometimes be null.  This causes a problem for me cause I call the `_mediator.Send` method with the null object and it throws an exception.

Understandably, the easy solution would be to check for null in the action and instantiate an object when required but I am reluctant to do this and would love a more elegant solution.

Is there a way to ensure I never receive null items as an action parameter?

Perhaps by intercepting the parameter binding step somehow...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this exact same problem with `Mediatr` not being happy about the null parameter but Web Api not allowing me to define it as nullable.

This is the most elegant solution I could come up with without messing with model binding logic.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns all objects
/// </summary>
/// <param name="request"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[Route("")]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<ObjectResponse>))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetObjects([FromUri] ObjectsGetRequest request) => 
  Ok(await this.mediator.Send(request ?? new ObjectsGetRequest()));
```

This only ever has to be done for `[FromUri]` annotated parameters so it doesn't seem that intrusive to me.

This is effectively the same as if each of the query string parameters was listed as a method parameter as a value type.

If you require one of the request parameter's values be defined by the requester, pull that out as a separate `[FromUri]` param and assign it to your request before sending it off to `Mediatr`